# ORA -00920 :invalid rational operator. SQL statement

Tags: sas

I tried running below query but getting operator error

```
Proc sql;
connect to oracle(path="xxx" connection =shared);
create table sample as 
select * from connection to oracle 
  (select * from ori.auto as a
  where "&start."d <= datepart(a.date) <= "&end."d);
  quit;
```

Error:

```
   ERROR: ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00920 :invalid rational operator.
```

Could you please help me correct this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use SAS date literals, e.g. `"&start"d`, in Oracle.

Use the syntax `date '2023-05-12'`

Oracle doesn't like double-quotes either, and macro variables won't normally resolve inside single-quotes. The SAS `%TSLIT` macro solves this problem.

```
/* Convert &start and &end to Oracle equivalents */
%LET START_ORA = %SYSFUNC(sum("&start"d,0),yymmdd10.) ;
%LET END_ORA = %SYSFUNC(sum("&end"d,0),yymmdd10.) ;

proc sql;
  connect to oracle(path="xxx" connection =shared);
  create table sample as 
  select * from connection to oracle 
  (select * from ori.auto as a
   where date between %TSLIT(&START_ORA) and date %TSLIT(&END_ORA)
  );
quit;
```